# jQuery select table only returning first tr

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Strange behaviour, it seems jQuery parse failed.

I want to select all tr on the table using this selector: `table#tblOutFlightBlocks tr`

jQuery return only first tr, please take a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ogy9b9d/

ps. HTML look OK

Thank you

Comment: do you want the html to include the `<tr>` tag also

Comment: Using tbody content: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6ogy9b9d/3/), Using tr content: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6ogy9b9d/4/)

Comment: No, I just need iterate each `tr` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html()` is invoked on a single element. so even though you are selecting all `tr` you are getting html or first one only. You can select all tr html by iterating on that array.

```
var allHtml = '';

$.each($('table#tblOutFlightBlocks tr'),function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    allHtml += tr.html();
});

alert(allHtml);
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n9632nd0/)

Comment: Thank you, all answer is correct. Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('table#tblOutFlightBlocks tr'),function(){
alert($(this).html());
})
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ogy9b9d/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var html='';
$('table#tblOutFlightBlocks tr').each(function(index,item){
   html += $(item).html();
})
alert (html);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ogy9b9d/2/)